# How to modify "Alt + o" combination to type "ö" character?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

I use a QWERTY English keyboard layout which I would like to assign some new characters for Turkish characters, such as hitting Alt+o at the same time should type ö.

What free tool do you recommend to perform this keyboard mapping in Windows?

PS: This was so simple in Fedora as the Turkish keyboard layout was overlaid on the default English keyboard, so I could continue typing without any hassle.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use Autoit or AutoHotKey to do simple key shortcuts such as that.

Answer (score 2):

Many people use the US-International keyboard layout to do that, if you press " and o it will give you ö. But if you often need to type quotes (as a developer, I know I do) this becomes a nuisance, because you need to press a space after " if you want a quote character.

I would personally recommend Unichars (http://unichars.sourceforge.net/). While it doesn't exactly let you map Alt+o to ö, it has a fairly extensive character set that you can access by pressing a magic key first (Configurable, I use Right-Ctrl), and then two or more keys that compose a special one. In your example, **"** and **o** would form **ö**.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution is to use [wincompose](https://github.com/SamHocevar/wincompose)

then modify WinCompose text file in the res folder as:

```
# Turkish characters
<Multi_key> <c>         : "ç"
<Multi_key> <C>         : "Ç"
<Multi_key> <g>         : "ğ" 
<Multi_key> <G>         : "Ğ"
<Multi_key> <i>         : "ı"
<Multi_key> <I>         : "İ"
<Multi_key> <o>         : "ö"
<Multi_key> <O>         : "Ö"
<Multi_key> <s>         : "ş"
<Multi_key> <S>         : "Ş"
<Multi_key> <u>         : "ü"
<Multi_key> <U>         : "Ü"
```

not the best solution, but seems to work so far.